# How to edit and repickle?

Tags: python, pickle

From what I understand, the only way to edit an object in a pickle file is to unpickle each object, edit the desired object, and repickle everything back into the original file.

This is what I tried doing:

```
pickleWrite = open(fileName, 'wb')
pickleRead = open(fileName, 'rb')

#unpickle objects and put it in dataList

dataList = list()

try:
  while True:
    dataList.append(pickle.load(pickleRead))
except EOFError:
  pass

#change desired pickle object

dataList[0] = some change

#clear pickle file
pickleWrite.truncate(0)

#repickle each item in data list

for data in dataList:
  pickle.dump(data, fileName)
```

For some reason, this makes the pickle file have some large number of unknown symbols at the front of the file making it unpickleable.

Error when we try to unpickle:

```
_pickle.UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.
```

Comment: Won't opening the file in `wb` mode overwrite it? You do that in the first line.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest avoiding to create multiple opened connection to the same file like this.

Instead, you can try:

```py
# Read the contents
with open(filename, 'rb') as file:
  dataList = pickle.load(file)

# something to dataList

# Overwrite the picle file
with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
  pickle.dump(dataList, file)
```